# group and label rows in data frame by numeric in R

Tags: r, dataset, grouping, rows

I need to group and label every x observations(rows) in a dataset in R.
I need to know if the last group of rows in the dataset has less than x observations

For example:
If I use a dataset with 10 observations and 2 variables and I want to group by every 3 rows.
I want to add a new column so that the dataset looks like this:

```
    speed     dist       newcol
        4        2            1
        4       10            1
        7        4            1
        7       22            2
        8       16            2
        9       10            2
       10       18            3
       10       26            3
       10       34            3
       11       17            4
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want, please give us some input-data, do you just simply want: `df$group <- c(rep(1:3, each = 3), 4)`

Comment: @grrgrrbla, this will not work if the `data.frame` number of rows cant be divided by `3`. One correct solution is `rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df)/3), each=3)[1:nrow(df)]`

Comment: I know, that this is not the solution, but I have no input-data and dont even understand what he wants, so I tried to get more information by giving a very simple solution, and asking if this is the direction

Comment: It is even not a very simple solution if it's false. But I agree the OP would need to detail a little bit more.

Comment: basically everybody understood from my simple example, what direction he wants to go to and basically improved on it, so it gave people a starting point, I dont care if it doesnt work for whatever special case, if I have no idea what he actually wants, I just replicated his example MANUALLY, to get a better sense for what he wants, which is way more constructive that to judge something without knowing what the parameters are, I never even used the word solution, I just asked for what he wants

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear: I am new to R.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear: I am new to R. Also, I'm a girl :-)  What I meant was, I want to write a function that will allow me to group and label rows in any data frame by any number (x) of rows in the order that they are listed. The data I gave and grouping into 3 rows at a time was an example.  The dataset could have any number of rows, and I might want to group by (for example) 5 rows at a time. Not sure if I'm making any sense here..... :/

Answer (score 2):

```
df$group <- rep(1:(nrow(df)/3), each = 3)
```

This works if the number of rows is an exact multiple of 3. Every three rows will get tagged in serial numbers.

A quick dirty way to tackle the problem of not knowing how incomplete the final group is to simply check the remained when nrow is modulus divided by group size: `nrow(df) %% 3 #change the divisor to your group size`

Answer (score 1):

assuming your data is `df` you can do

```
df$newcol = rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df)/3), each = 3)[1:nrow(df)]
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! Though it doesn't come up with a notice when there are less than 3 in the final grouping. Would you know how to get it to come back with that?

Comment: it keeps the first `nrow(df)` of the vector formed by `rep` function.